# How can I use CountVectorizer with aggregated data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm working on [goodbooks-10k dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/zygmunt/goodbooks-10k) to make a recommender system. I want to use the tags of the books to make recommendations. Tags of the books come in an aggrageted way - for every book and every tag, there is a row with the name of the book, the name of the tag, and the number of the times this tag occurred for this book.
The dataset looks like this:

[image]

I want to use this information to build a bag-of-words representation of the tags, where for every tag I have a column with the number of times this tag occurs for the book given.

What is the proper way to implement this with pandas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The image link is useful, but since it's relatively simple, could you cut and paste the data into your question so we have it for quick reference? You can use 3 backticks ``` to make code/data blocks.

Comment: dt.tag_id.value_counts()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

Sample dataframe:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({"book_id": [1,1,2,2,3], "tag_id": [100, 120, 130, 140, 150], "tag_count": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]})

# df

#   book_id tag_id  tag_count
#  0    1    100    100
#  1    1    120    200
#  2    2    130    300
#  3    2    140    400
#  4    3    150    500
```

```
df.pivot_table(values="tag_count", index="book_id", columns="tag_id", aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
# tag_id    100 120 130 140 150
# book_id                   
#  1    100 200 0   0   0
#  2    0   0   300 400 0
#  3    0   0   0   0   500
```

Comment: Thanks! However, when I do that the new dataframe has only 812 rows, but the old one contains of 10,000 books. I have: 
`books_with_tags = pd.merge(b, tags_join_DF, left_on='book_id', right_on='goodreads_book_id', how='outer')` .     
`books_with_tags["book_id"].value_counts()` has lenght of 10000. But the new dataframe after `books_with_tags.pivot_table(values="count", index="book_id", columns="tag_name", aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0)` has only 812 rows. Do you know why is that?

Comment: Once you spread the dataframe using pivot_table, most of the information from rows will transfer to columns, hence lesser no. of rows. In answer above, after pivoting you get only 3 instead of original 5 rows. But all the information is still preserved